# Can we use Apache IVY for dependency management without Ant?

Tags: maven, ant, ivy

Currently we are using Maven for build purpose. For dependency management, I know Apache Ivy is best (correct me if I am wrong). But it is completly dependent on Ant.But we are not using Ant in my application. Can I use IVY without Ant? Please provide the best approach in this scenario for dependency management?

Comment: I would tend to correct you, Ivy is basically made to add dependency management (backported from how Maven does that) to an Ant build. Reverting from a Maven-based build to an Ivy + Ant would be a huge step in the wrong direction

Comment: The question is: What is the reason to goto Ant+Ivy instead of Maven? What does not work or what kind of problem would you like to solve?

Comment: Hi khmarbaise,                                                                                        The Maven build script relies on external sources,which could allow an attacker to insert malicious code into the final product or to take control of the build machine.(Please correct me if am wrong)

Comment: You can definitely use it [standalone](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/standalone.html). I personally use it for dependency and build artifact management for my c++ projects and typeset documents, with a private repository (using Artifactory). No Ant involved at all.